# Knowing the Source of a website?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a website, that redirects to another website like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Site 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://page2.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://page2.com"
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        If you are not redirected automatically, click
        <a href='http://page2.com'>here</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Now on the receiving page; page2.com, how can I know if the user came from page1 or some other page? If they come from another source, I dont need to know. I only need to know if they came from my redirect page or not.

Comment: You can check the "referrer" HTTP header, but that's not guaranteed and can be easily modified by browser extensions and such.

Comment: Is there a more 'secure' way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var x = document.referrer;
alert(x);
if (x == 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236796/knowing-the-source-of-a-website/35236811')
alert('hi stackoverflower');
</script>
```

Example: http://ec2-52-49-115-131.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php